# Possible to not allow deleting a model, but allow it being destroyed as a dependency in Rails/ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Because of dependency issues, I cannot destroy a particular object `a`. The way to destroy it is by destroying a different object `b` that has `dependent: :destroy` for its `belongs_to` association to `a`:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  #don't ever delete this directly
  has_one :b, dependent: :destroy
end
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  #delete this object instead and it will automatically delete A
  belongs_to :a, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Is there a way to specify that deleting `a` is not allowed, but still allow it to be deleted when `b` is deleted?

I can put this in `A`:

```
before_destroy :prevent_destroy

private
def prevent_destroy
  false
end
```

but then `A` won't be deleted as a dependency of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly. Could

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  #don't ever delete this directly
  has_one :b, dependent: :restrict
end
```

work for you?

Comment: is that what `:restrict` does, does not allow deleting directly if `b` exists?

Comment: Yes. If it has any associated objects, Rails will not allow to destroy a particular object.

Comment: but wouldn't it also not be allowed to be deleted through a dependency mechanism too? I basically need it to be deleted if it was done so as a dependent of a destroyed object, but it shouldn't be allowed to be deleted if I try to do so directly.

Comment: How about use a class variable as a flag, and provide a interface to access the variable. In B, add something like: "before_destroy :set_flag_ture; after_destroy :set_flag_false". In A: "before_destroy :check_flag_if_true". And the flag is the class variable or global variable value that could be accessed by a interface or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `destroyed_by_association` is set in the callback. Something like:

```
before_destroy :prevent_destroy

private
def prevent_destroy
  destroyed_by_association     #nil is falsey
end
```

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html#method-i-destroyed_by_association